# Compare $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) dx \quad\text{ and }\quad \lim_{t\rightarrow +\infty} \int_{-t}^{t} f(x) dx$

Tags: integration, analysis, improper-integrals

> I would like to compare these two integrals
>
> ### $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) dx \quad\text{ and }\quad \lim_{t\rightarrow +\infty} \int_{-t}^{t} f(x) dx$$

**My Thoughts:**

Let  $\displaystyle I=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)dx$, and $\displaystyle J=\lim_{t \to +\infty} \int_{-t}^{+t} f(x)dx.$

- If $I$ exist, then $J$ exists, and $I=J$ :
- If $I$ exists, Then $\displaystyle I = \lim_{u \to -\infty} \lim_{v \to +\infty} \int_{u}^{v} f(x)dx = \lim_{u \to +\infty} \lim_{v \to +\infty}
   \int_{-u}^{v} f(x)dx =\lim_{t \to +\infty} \lim_{t \to +\infty} \int_{-t}^{t} f(x)dx = J.$

**The converse is false.**

- *Conter-example* : $\displaystyle f(x) = x.$
- $\displaystyle J=\lim_{t \to +\infty} \int_{-t}^{+t} f(x)dx = \lim_{t \to +\infty}  \int_{-t}^{+t} xdx = \lim_{t \to +\infty} \frac{x^2}{2} \mid_{-t}^{+t}  =\lim_{t \to +\infty} \ 0=0 .$ then $J$ exists.
- $\displaystyle \lim_{v \to +\infty} \int_{u}^{v} f(x)dx = \lim_{v \to +\infty} \int_{u}^{v} xdx =\lim_{v \to +\infty} \frac{x^2}{2} \mid_{u}^{v} =
   \lim_{v \to +\infty} (\frac{v^2}{2}-\frac{u^2}{2}) = +\infty.$ then $I$  doesn't exists.
- Is my proof correct also I'm interested in more ways of proving it

Comment: Yes.  All is correct.

Comment: Is there any other way ?

Comment: Yes.  One way to show this is to use [Cauchy's Criterion](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/rdaileda/teach/m4342f10/improper_integrals.pdf)